# What happened to the answer to this stock photo question?

Tags: discussion

When I first saw this [question and its answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103524/where-was-this-stock-photo-taken), one of the answers was apparently from the actual photographer, and he had described details of how he took the photo, how he digitally enhanced it and finally made the version in the question. At the time, that answer had even more up-votes than the accepted one.

However, now it seems the answer is gone. Why was it deleted? It seemed to be a good answer and a good addition to the site. Was it deleted by a moderator or by the owner? Is there anyway to get it back?

Answer (score 13):

It was deleted by the owner for some reason:

[image]

Usually we frown upon deleting your own content unless it has been posted recently or heavily downvoted. In this case the owner deleted his post in less than 24 hours after submitting it, so I think we should respect his wishes and keep it deleted.

Comment: The "owner" no longer appears to be a user of the site? (Unless they've just changed their name?)

Comment: @MrWhite You can tell if the owner has deleted their account if their username ("user-----") isn't a link and is grayed out.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος Yes, but that assumes you can see their username. In this case, the answer was deleted, and I don't have >10K on this site to see the deleted answer. I just so happened to remember the username as I'd read the question earlier. But a quick search for this username returns no results.

Comment: @MrWhite they did delete their profile.

Comment: Questions and Answers posted on this site are [licensed under CC-SA-BY](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/licensing) so it's perfectly reasonable to undelete the answer or to copy and paste it to a new answer with attribution.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this answer is good content, and it is unfortunate that it was deleted, even though it was the owner who did it. I think a case could be made that the community might choose to undelete this answer.

[image]

Comment: Users with 15k+ rep can vote to undelete.